# NGINX configuration wildcard

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I am using Symfony2 (PHP) framework for my project and is having a small problem with regards to configuring my NGINX to catch request going to a 3rd party library I placed under "web" directory.

This is my configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.com;
    root /var/www/my-symfony-project/web;

    rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    location / {
        index app.php;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

As you may have noticed that the root is pointed in "/var/www/my-symfony-project/web" directory.

Now, the problem is that I have this "some-plugin" folder inside the "web" directory and there are PHP files from there that are not handled by the Symfony2 routing.

I actually made it work when I have the following "location" block inside the "server" block illustrated above.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

It seems okay having this type of configuration at first but we realized that it accepts request to any "*.php" file to which we evaluated as a security breach.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing access to `.php` files is usually not considered dangerous or a security breach, as long as the PHP files are executed and not served in their source form and, of course, don't print any sensitive information.
If either of the former are **not** the case, you should probably change your setup or your code.

Anyway, you should be able to restrict the `.php` file handling to `/var/www/my-symfony-project/web/some-plugin` by using the following as `location`:

```
location ~ ^/var/www/my-symfony-project/web/some-plugin/.*\.php$ {
    # your rules here
}
```

This should match all files whose path starts with `/var/www/my-symfony-project/web/some-plugin/` and end with `.php` in upper or lower case.